# If I want to make sure the NSMutableArray I return is treated only as an NSArray, is copy what I should be using? A cast?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, nsarray

So I'm using `NSUserDefaults` and I want to make sure I save an `NSArray` instead of an `NSMutableArray`. I'm dealing with an `NSMutableArray` prior to saving it, however, and I want to know how I'd best save it.

Should I do `setObject:[mutableArray copy]`? Or `[setObject:(NSArray *)mutableArray]`? A third option?

I was leaning toward `copy`, as it seems like the natural counterpart to `mutableCopy`, however wasn't copy used extensively pre-ARC for something different? I thought `copy` calls when `autorelease` was still prevalent were used for something distinct.

Comment: You could simply use `setObject:mutableArray`.

Comment: It needs to be noted strongly that (in the general case -- not specific to NSUserDefaults) simply casting to NSArray will not prevent a mutable array from being modified.  It must be actually copied, one way or another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults` already saves a `NSArray`, even if you pass a `NSMutableArray`.

For other situations, `copy` with ARC is perfectly fine to use. Also, you don't need a cast because a `NSMutableArray` pointer, for polymorphism is compatible with a `NSArray` pointer (but not viceversa).

Comment: What about another situation where I need to ensure it's an NSArray?

Comment: In this case you should copy it.

Comment: Just to be clear, `copy` always creates an immutable copy (i.e. a copy of an NSMutableArray is an NSArray).  Similarly, `mutableCopy` always creates a mutable copy.

Comment: @titaniumdecoy So there's no issues with past memory management usage?

Comment: @DougSmith No, there are not.